# Where's LiveRail's API's PHP class (for downloading reports, etc.)?

Tags: php, api, liverail

LiveRail's API documentation links to **"LiveRailAPI PHP class"** but it's a dead link:
http://test.api.liverail.com/LiveRailAPI.zip / https://test.api.liverail.com/LiveRailAPI.zip (LR links to the former but writes the latter).

Does anyone happen to have it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the class' new home is a secret invite-only repository within https://github.com/liverail.

Comment: That is correct. Please reach out to your account manager or support@liverail.com with your entity ID, and we'll be happy to get you set up with access to our private code repo.